# Quickbooks API - 'A temporary issue prevented this request from being processed'

Tags: java, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

Using Quickbooks payments api I have successfully created a credit card and a charge against it. Now I am trying to refund the charge.
But I am repeatedly getting "A temporary issue prevented this request from being processed" error when calling /refunds api.

```
Error com.intuit.ipp.exception.BadRequestException: ERROR CODE:PMT-6000, ERROR MESSAGE:A temporary issue prevented this request from being processed., ERROR DETAIL:null, MORE ERROR DETAIL:HttpStatusCode=400; Type=system_error; MoreInfo=null, InfoLink=https://developer.intuit.com/v2/docs?redirectID=PayErrors
```

Below are my create card, create charge and charge refund requests.

**Create credit card request**

```
{
  "number" : "5105105105105100",
  "expMonth" : "10",
  "expYear" : "2022",
  "cvc" : "1234",
  "name" : "Test User"
}
```

**Create charge request**

```
{
  "amount" : 100.00,
  "currency" : "USD",
  "capture" : true,
  "cardOnFile" : "102152906604139312775100",
  "context" : {
    "mobile" : false
  }
}
```

**Create refund request**

```
https://sandbox.api.intuit.com/quickbooks/v4/payments/charges/E3GVE5S1JEN7/refunds
```

The error is not very informative. Can someone please guide how can I find the exact reason for the error.

> RESOLVED

I think I was using API wrong as pointed out by Lino in the comment. `/refunds` API can accept few arguments in the request body but all of those arguments are optional. I assumed since these arguments are optional I can invoke API without including any request body. I was following these [API docs](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/00_quickbooks_online/2_build/60_tutorials/use_the_quickbooks_online_and_the_quickbooks_payments_apis_together#/Creating_a_refund)

 The example there is incomplete without any request body.
After including request body now I can successfully create a refund.

Comment: You get a 400 status error, which means `Bad Request` so probably you're using the API wrong

Comment: I am making the API call exactly the way it is documented here at - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/payments/charges.
It's POST request and the API call doesn't have a request body, just the charge id in the URI itself. I am doing exactly that. Not sure what's wrong.